# How can I put the content of a file in a Tkinter Text?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to put the content of a py file in a **Tkinter Text widget** when I open the file from a **tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile**. Here's the code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import tkinter.messagebox
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
import tkinter.filedialog


myfonts = {'times': 'times 18 bold', 'verdana': 'Verdana 10'}
mypatterns = [('Python', '*.py'), ('Python', '*.pyw')]


class IdlePlus(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, class_='IdlePlus')
        self.master = parent
        self.master.title('IDLE Plus')
        self.master.geometry('500x500+250+50')
        self.master.configure(bg='orange')

        self.master.bind('<Control-q>', self.idleplusQuit)
        self.master.bind('<Control-o>', self.myfileOpen)

        self.myBarMenu()

        self.myNoteBook()

    def myfileOpen(self):
        self.myfile = tk.filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=mypatterns,
                                  title='Open a Python file', mode='rb')
        loadedfile = self.myfile.read()
        self.myfile.close()
        print(loadedfile)

    def myNoteBook(self):
        self.notebook = ttk.Notebook(self.master, width=500, height=600)
        self.framenotebook1 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.framenotebook2 = ttk.Frame(self.notebook)
        self.notebook.add(self.framenotebook1, text='One')
        self.notebook.add(self.framenotebook2, text='Two')
        self.notebook.pack(side='top', expand='yes', fill='both')
        self.scrollbarView = tk.Scrollbar(self.framenotebook1,
                                          orient='vertical', takefocus=False,
                                          highlightthickness=0)
        self.textView = tk.Text(self.framenotebook1, bg='blue', fg='white',
                         wrap='word', highlightthickness=0)
        self.scrollbarView.config(command=self.textView.yview)
        self.textView.config(yscrollcommand=self.scrollbarView.set)
        self.scrollbarView.pack(side='right', fill='y')
        self.textView.pack(side='left', expand='yes', fill='both')

    def myBarMenu(self):
        mymenubar = tk.Menu(self.master)

        filemenu = tk.Menu(mymenubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label='New File', underline=0,
                             accelerator='CTRL+N')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Open File', underline=0,
                            accelerator='CTRL+O', command=self.myfileOpen)
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label='Save File', underline=0,
                             accelerator='CTRL+S')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Save As...', accelerator='CTRL+SHIFT+S')
        filemenu.add_command(label='Close File', underline=0,
                             accelerator='ALT+F4')
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label='Print File', underline=0,
                             accelerator='CTRL+P')
        filemenu.add_separator()
        filemenu.add_command(label='Exit', underline=0,
                             accelerator='CTRL+Q', command=self.idleplusQuit)
        mymenubar.add_cascade(label='File', underline=0, menu=filemenu)

        aboutmenu = tk.Menu(mymenubar, tearoff=0)
        aboutmenu.add_command(label='Help', underline=0, accelerator='F1')
        aboutmenu.add_command(label='About IDLE-Plus', underline=0)
        mymenubar.add_cascade(label='Help', underline=0, menu=aboutmenu)

        self.master.configure(menu=mymenubar)

    def idleplusQuit(self, event=None):
        if tk.messagebox.askokcancel('Quit', 'Do you really want to exit?',
                                     parent=self.master):
            self.master.destroy()


window = tk.Tk()
myapp = IdlePlus(window)
window.mainloop()
```

I want to put the content **loadedfile in self.textView**, actually the content appears printed fine in a terminal.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def myfileOpen(self):
    self.myfile = tk.filedialog.askopenfile(filetypes=mypatterns,
                              title='Open a Python file', mode='r')
    loadedfile = self.myfile.read()
    self.myfile.close()
    self.textView.insert("end", loadedfile)
```

[I used this tutorial](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html#basics)

Comment: ok, it works, but i have a little problem, How can I specify encoding=utf-8? askopenfile doesn't have this option.

Comment: in python 3 when you open file with `mode='r'` the default encoding  is utf-8. But you can open a file in binary mode `mode='rb` and then decode its using utf-8. I cant remember how, buts its one of the python libraries.